# testing median value of top x% of sample value against median of top x% of of population

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, sample

I have a random sample from population. I want to prove/un-prove that  median/mean value of top x% of random sample represents the median/mean value of top x%  of population.  I have two questions:

1. How to decide the sample size to test above.
2. What are the relevant statistical tests that can help me to conclude this.

Answer (score 0):

The median of the top fraction $p$ is the $1-p/2$ quantile, so you would appear in the end to just be comparing a population quantile with a sample quantile. For example, the median of the top 50% is  the upper quartile.

The most obvious way to test that is to compute the sample proportion above the population quantile representing that "median of the top x%" and compare it with x/2%, which should be a binomial proportion.

As a result, the usual binomial-proportion sample size calculations would apply.

However you can't "prove" they're the same. You can show they're different. Or if you do something like an equivalence test you can show they're very close together (not outside some bound)